# rotar una imagen 90 grados

Tags: java, array

tengo un problema de código con este método rotar90ALaDerecha().

Enunciado
Escriba un método que sea capaz de rotar una imagen 90 grados a la derecha.

Este es mi código:

```
/**
* Rota la imagen 90 grados hacia la derecha
*/
public void rotar90ALaDerecha()
{
    Color temp[][]= new Color[ALTO_MAXIMO][ANCHO_MAXIMO];
    for(int i=0; i<alto;i++)
      {
        for(int j=0; j<ancho;j++)
        {
            temp[j][alto-1-i]=bitmap[i][j];
        }
      }
      bitmap = new Color[ANCHO_MAXIMO][ALTO_MAXIMO];
      bitmap = temp;
}
```

Me sale este error:

El alto de la imagen no cambio, al rotar deberia cambiarse por el ancho original. Se esperaba 300, pero usted respondió 200 
expected:

Nota: aqui dejo el diagrama de clases y muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

https://cupiexamenes.virtual.uniandes.edu.co/media/web/modelos-mundo/15bc13c8598.jpg

Comment: ¿Como y en donde cargas la imagen?, me parece que eso es importante.

Comment: En un método que aparte  carga la imagen, este es otro método aparte... mejor dicho la clase esta lista pero tengo que adicionarle otras funciones y ademas de esta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void rotar90ALaDerecha() {
    int ancho = bitmap[0].length;
    int alto = bitmap.length;

    Color temp[][]= new Color[ancho][alto];
    int nuevaColumna = alto - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < alto; i++, nuevaColumna--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ancho; j++) {
            temp[j][nuevaColumna] = bitmap[i][j];
        }
    }
    bitmap = temp;
}
```

Esto `bitmap = new Color[ANCHO_MAXIMO][ALTO_MAXIMO];` no es necesario ya que lo que estás haciendo es reservando espacio en memoria para una nueva matriz y estás poniendo a apuntar `bitmap` a dicha matriz y en la linea de abajo vuelves a cambiar la referencia de `bitmap` y lo pones a apuntar a `temp`. Por tal motivo estás reservando espacio en memoria innecesario.

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda tiene mucha lógica tu código pero aun me sale el siguiente error después de modificarlo:                                                        El alto de la imagen no cambio, al rotar deberia cambiarse por el ancho original. Se esperaba 300, pero usted respondió 200 
expected:<java.awt.Color[r=0,g=146,b=70], pero usted respondió null

Comment: Acabo de ´modificar el código para que tome los valores de la matriz `bitmap`. Está probado y funciona 100%.

Comment: Ya me aparece el siguiente error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 300

Comment: Si, disculpa cambia esta línea `int nuevaColumna = ancho;` por esta `int nuevaColumna = alto - 1;`, modificando mi código se me fue eso. Espero que con esto ya te funcione.

Comment: le he modificado pero aun no arroja el resultado esperado, que pena molestarlo tanto este es el resultado:                                                                 El alto de la imagen no cambio, al rotar deberia cambiarse por el ancho original. Se esperaba 300, pero usted respondió 200 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 299

Comment: Podrías poner el código de tu método de rotar completo.

Comment: public void rotar90ALaDerecha()
{
    int ancho = bitmap[0].length;
    int alto = bitmap.length;

    Color temp[][]= new Color[ancho][alto];
    int nuevaColumna = alto - 1 ;
    for(int i = 0; i < alto; i++, nuevaColumna--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < ancho; j++) {
            temp[j][nuevaColumna] = bitmap[i][j];
        }
    }
    bitmap = temp;
}

Comment: Acabo de agregar una imagen de la prueba que acabo de realizar con tu mismo código (solo cambié el tipo de dato de la matriz a `int` para que se vea mejor). Te recomiendo que revises el código de tus pruebas.

Comment: si tu código esta bien yo creo que es la herramienta . aun sigue con el mismo error,  muchas gracias por tu tiempo muy amable.

Answer (score 0):

Os falta cambiar el tamaño de la imagen. Si no,te da el error de que se sale del array.

```
    int anchoaux =ancho;
    int altoaux =alto;
    Color temp[][]=new Color[anchoaux][altoaux];
    int columnaExtra = altoaux-1;
    for (int i=0; i<altoaux;i++,columnaExtra--) 
    {
        for (int j=0;j<anchoaux;j++) 
        {
            temp[j][columnaExtra]=bitmap[ i ][ j ];
        }
    }
      /* 

       * cambiar el alto por el ancho y el ancho por el alto
       */

      alto=anchoaux;
      ancho=altoaux;
      bitmap=temp;
```