# PROBLEMA PARA ROTAR UNA IMAGEN 90 GRADOS EN JAVA

Tags: java

tengo un inconveniente con el siguiente código,por más que lo modifico no se rota correctamente la imagen, me recomendaron crear un nuevo bitmap para almacenar la imagen rotada pero honestamente no entiendo cómo implementar el código correctamente:

```
/**
* Rota la imagen 90 grados hacia la derecha
*/
public void rotar90ALaDerecha() {

    final int ancho = bitmap.length;
    final int alto = bitmap[0].length;

    Color[][] bitmapRotado = new Color[ALTO_MAXIMO][ANCHO_MAXIMO];

    for(int i = 0, j = ancho-1 ; i < ancho ; i++, j--) 
    {
        for(int k = 0 ; k < alto ; k++)
        {
            bitmapRotado[k][j] = bitmap[i][k];
        }
    }

    bitmap = bitmapRotado;
}
```

adjunto el mapa de clases:

[image: mapa de clases]

Comment: Como obtienes el bitmap?

Comment: public Imagen( String archivo ) throws IOException
    {
        bitmap = new Color[ALTO_MAXIMO][ANCHO_MAXIMO];
        cargarImagen( archivo );
    }

Comment: la declaracionn del atributo bitmap es:  private Color bitmap[][];

Comment: El còdigo que comentas no indica como cargas la imagen, estas usando JavaFX?

Comment: El problema es que esa no es una imágen, es un arreglo bidisimensoinal de colores. Las imágenes en su forma más básica no tienen colkores dentro, tienen bytes o vectores.

Comment: adicionalmente te reomienod usar transformaciones afines que ya trae Java2D para rotar mediante algebr de matrices en vez de cambiar los elementos píxel por píxel.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [rotar una imagen 90 grados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137140/rotar-una-imagen-90-grados)

Comment: @RuslanLópez muchas gracias amigo!